# Windows phone - how to make a button that has two text elements

Tags: windows-phone-7, button, windows-phone-8

I am wondering what would be the easiest/best way to make a button that has two text elements. One on the left side and another on the right.

[image: example]

First I was thinking to place a TextBlock on top of a Button, but the TextBlock should change color like the Button's text does when the Button is pressed etc. and I haven't found a way to do this perfectly. Also I would like a bit smoother solution.

Should I inherit the Button and make my own version? And is there some example or tutorial somewhere out there that would help on this?

I haven't done much with Windows Phone before as you can probably guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is several variants in your case

1. Put Container with two TextBlocks inside Button

   ```
   <Button>
     <Grid>
       <Grid.ColumnDefenitions>
         <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
         <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
       </Grid.ColumnDefenitions>
       <TextBlock Text="TIME"/>
       <TextBlock Text="2:20" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
     </Grid>
   </Button>
   ```
2. Another option is to use StringFormat, if you use Binding

   ```
   <Button Content="{Binding time, StringFormat={}TIME {0:t}}"" />
   ```

Comment: Forgot Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right". Edited my answer